# Is there limit on the number of data points to plot HighChart

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller, highcharts

I am using HighChart to plot Graph of the Telemetry data saved in cloud

> Data Points on X-Axis is : Time
>
> Data Points on Y-Axis is : Value

**My Issue**:

When the data requested is huge say >9000, HighChart errs out and doesn't plot the graph. (Note : I haven't checked the count limit , Hight Chart is able to plot- but when the number is smaller it always plots the graph)

**What is the limit of data**

Is there any limit of data to plot the graph?
Or is it that I have missed out something that handles this.

Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

The graph used to plot Chart in my app is

```
var chart_PT1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'signal_high_container'//'PT_1_high_container',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'IO Signal  Data'
        },
        
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: GPS Modem'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

                
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        //categories: dddDate,
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () { return ddd[this.value][0]; },//<===== throw error here

        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: ddd,
        name: SignalName
    }]
});
});
```

It throws an exception in formatter at `ddd[this.value][0]` saying something like *the index for ddd[this.value] not valid*

```
 xAxis: {
           ....
                formatter: function () { return ddd[this.value][0]; },//<===== throw error here
```

Comment: Does the error still occur if you comment out whole `formatter` line?

Comment: Note that if you are planning to plot a lot of points, using the boost module is a good idea. Have a look at: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of highcharts have a turboThreshold option under plot options that places restrictions on data > 1000 plots. Look-up 'turboThreshold' in the docs for a better explanation.

Ref: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Comment: So is it possible to plot ten thousands ++ data points on HighChart setting  say 'turboThreshold:20000'. _____If not what is the limit to be set here ____which I need to make the client aware of?

Comment: Set it to 0 disable, but there is no documentation to say max supporting limit